# subtracting two's complement for beginner

Tags: binary, cpu-architecture

Guys need some help to solve a question. I am trying to learning Complement notation which is in my bca course. Recently i finished the 2's complement notation chapter, ans stuck at question.
Can some one describe me that how to subtract

a)10 from 14

b)14 from 10

using 2's complement notation.

What i have done is

Above numbers in binary.
10=1010
14=1110

two's complement of the two numbers.
1010=>0101+1=0110
1110=>1110+1=1111

Now i am stuck how will i solve the

a)Subtraction of 10 from 14

b)Subtraction of 14 from 10

Please use descriptive way so i can understand each step for both subtraction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To get Two's Compliment you invert the bits. To Subtract, you add one side of the expression to the Two's Compliment of the other. I don't understand what you mean by notation.

Comment: @Jodrell my question here is the BCA exam question. I need to find Perform 2’s complement subtraction of following:
A) 10 from 14
b) 14 from 10

Answer (score 1):

At last, we have found the solution

---

10 in binary 00001010
2's complement of 10 is 0110

14 in binary 00001110
2's complement of 14 is 0010

4 in binary 0000 0100
2's complement of 4 is 1111 1100

### 2's Complement Subtraction=>

10 - 14  =  (-4)      0000 1010  =  +10

### + 1111 0010  =  -14

### 1111 1100  =  -4

### 2's Complement Addition=>

14 - 10  =  (+4)      0000 1110  =  +14

### + 1111 0110  =  -10

### 10000 0100  =  +4

Answer (score 0):

Once you are done with 2' complement,
You just need to add it.

Subtraction of 14 from 10
1010=>0101+1=0110  [This means -10]
14 + (-10)

1110 
+

## 0110

0100 [Do not worry about the carry]

Comment: and substraction on 10 from 14 ?

Comment: Can you plz divide the answer into steps. I am at beginner level and it is difficult to understand in one step.. it will be great help if you describe both a and b separately in steps plz

Comment: See if this helps you, this has detailed example.
http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080731005158AApeCfL
Please mark the thread as solved once you understand it.

Comment: there are two question above. The main question is i need to check how both work. 10 - 14 and 14 - 10.The above answer is only for Subtraction of 14 from 10. Still Option A is missing

Answer (score 0):

Subtraction of 10 from 14

10=1010 14=1110

2's complement of 1110 is 0010

```
  1 0 1 0 + 0 0 1 0 = 1 1 0 0
```

2's complement of 1100 is 0100
 10  -  14 = -4
1010 - 1110 =0100